# How to import Twitter Fabric Kit into my iOS Static Framework

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-frameworks, twitter-fabric, twitter-login

I am creating an iOS static framework
I want to integrate Login with Twitter into my Framework.
To do this I have downloaded and installed Twitter Fabric Tool, from which I will install the 'Twitter' Kit.

The problem that I'm facing is that if I select my iOS Static Framework Project and click on 'Next' button in the Fabric interface, it gives an error message like 'This Xcode project does not have any Mac or iOS targets'. [Here's a screenshot of what I'm seeing in the Fabric Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbJxL.png)

What needs to be done if I want to integrate this into my Static iOS Framework.
Has anyone worked on this before and faced similar issue. 
Any insights into this would be really helpful.

Comment: Bump. Any help will be much appreciated!